# WCF service to Android Client - Errors: Could not find class & NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, wcf, runtime-error

I'm working on a project where I'm using WCF **(.Net Framework 4)** as my web service and an Android application as my client **(Android 2.2 (API 8))**. 
I created my WCF project, and published it onto an IIS Server.  Then I used the "wsimport" (the one provided by the java JDK) command using the following structure:

```
wsimport -p testWCF -keep -verbose -d "d:\webservice\java" http://192.168.2.103/MyWebService.svc?wsdl
```

I imported the jar file by pasting it in the Androids project's  "libs" folder, and adding the jar file to the build path by clicking the "Add External jar.." button.  Then checked the jar file in the "order and export" tab as shown below:

[Image of my "Build Path"](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15975895/stackoverflow/error.png)

From Eclipse I'm getting the following message:

```
The type javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

However Eclipse still runs the android project on my device, but then I get the following errors from Log Cat

- Could Not Find Class
- NoClassDefFoundError

When I imported the jar file into a normal java project I managed to access the web service successfully using the following code, but not in the android project.

```
MyWebService service = new MyWebService();
IMyWebService client = service.getBasicHttpBindingIMyWebService();

System.out.println(client.getMessage());
```

I searched the above errors and many solutions suggested that there are missing references in the "Build path", however these solutions did not work for my android project....What am I doing wrong? what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: I am facing with this issue too. Anyone could help!!!